# Python: form a TABLE with 1D lists as columns

Tags: python, list, arraylist, datatables, multiple-columns

I've been struggling for hours now trying to make a table of three columns of lists, I don't even know whether it's possible to do that or if I'd better try another alternative, I'm open to any suggestion as long as I can form the following table: a table giving the date and time of each result.

```
No_list=[1,2,3]
dates_list=["02 Jan 2021", "02 Jen 2021", "02 Jan 2021"]
hours_list=["13:00","13:01","13:02"]
results_list=[3,6,9]
```

I want to have the No_list as the first column, dates_list as the second, hours_list as the third and results_list as the fourth.

I could really use some help on this one, haven't found anything much helpful on the net but I'm sure some of you out there will be able to help me or at least suggest some kinda solution to obtain this table from these lists.

Thank you so much for your time,

Rouba

Comment: Have you tried using a pandas DataFrame? You should be able to create one directly from your lists by putting the lists in a list and passing it as data.

Comment: I don't even know what that is. I don't know what the notion of DataFrames means. I'm in first year of  uni but the exercices we are given are way out of range of what we've being taught in class. But thanks I'm gonna google that.

Comment: Oh by data frame u only mean 2D table, okay... I'm sorry I take my classes in french. you mean I should form a 2D list from my lists and then make the table. Yea makes sense but the problem is that It will look like that final_list = [[content of No_list] ,[content of dates_list],...] when I have no idea how to make that look right, cz in that case I will have each of my lists on a line when what I need is each as a column. Unless I got you wrong. :)

Answer (score 0):

Modules and libraries are made to make our programmming easier so why not use them when we are allowed to. Thanks @Ryan Goding, left with no other choice I finally used the pandas module and reached my goal with a few lines of code. The only downside would be the fact that I have this indexing on the right but it ain't much of a big deal when 2 lines of code solved what I would have needed loops and conditional statements to solve.

```
dico= {"Date     ":liste_date,"Heure ":liste_heure,"Relevé":liste_resultats}
#Dictionnaire contennat les colonnes de mon tableau en tant que listes
#Le titre de ces colonnes est désigné par la clé de chaque element 
Tableau = pd.DataFrame(data=dico)
#Utilisation du module pandas pour former ce tableau 
print(Tableau)
```

I simply created a dictionary with the title of my columns as a keys and printed it.
Thanks again Ryan for guiding me, otherwise I'd still be looking for a way to form my table from a 2D list.